# Maven dependency for commons-fileupload and commons-io

Tags: maven, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, apache-commons-fileupload

I want to add commons-fileupload and commons-io libraries to my project via STS.
when i tried to add dependency at my pom.xml and update it, i kept on received below errors for all the version

```
Maven dependency problem
    ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.1: 
    ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to transfer commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:pom:1.1 from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. 

    Original error: Could not transfer artifact commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:pom:1.1 from/to central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Connect times out
```

I tried to lookup from mvn:

```
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io/2.4
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload/1.2.2
```

I don't have issue with other libraries, especially commons-logging.
I'm using **SpringSource Tool Suite Version: 2.9.2.RELEASE** for my Spring Project.

Comment: seems that you have a connection problem (`Connect times out`). Please try this url in your browser: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/2.4/

Comment: Also delete the relevant folders from your local repo so that maven will retry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First remove your local repository (may be only the commons-io etc folder) furthermore check only Maven Central under the following URL:

```
http://search.maven.org/
```

where you find the your needed dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I use Maven and when I put 1.3 as version for commons-fileupload, maven automatically resolves version 2.2 for commons-io . I am wondering why it does not resolve to version 2.4 as in your example.

Comment: May be there is a dependencyManagement block in a parent pom defined?